# ASP.NET MVC / C# - Linq and hashed password

Tags: c#, linq, md5

I'm trying to create authentication where all passwords are hashed and salted. First, for simplicity, I tried without salt, here's my linq:

```
var CurrentUser = db.Users
    .Single(u => u.UserName == form["username"] && u.Password.SequenceEqual
               (
                   MD5.Create().ComputeHash
                       (
                           Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(form["password"])
                       )
               )
          );
```

Unfortunately, this error occurred:

The query operator 'SequenceEqual' is not supported.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would help to know where you're getting your user records from (i.e. what is "db.Users").

Whatever linq provider your using (EF etc) probably doesn't support using SequenceEqual in a query, so you'll need to grab the user record, then check the password:

```
var currentUser = db.Users.Single(u => u.UserName == form["username"]);
var hash = MD5.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(form["password"]));

var passwordCorrect = currentUser.Password.SequenceEqual(hash);
```

You may also want to be more explicit in your "u.UserName ==" comparison to make it obvious whether it's case insensitive/ordinal etc.

Edit: Flater's answer will also work fine, but personally I'd rather pull the record back and verify it as you may want to know whether the user actually exists or not (not just whether the username and password are correct) so you can "lock out" accounts or take other (more helpful) action based on a number of incorrect password attempts.

Comment: I've never worked too much with hashes before, thanks for the credit ;) You get an upvote on elaborating better than me :)

Answer (score 1):

LINQ doesn't allow every kind of function/operator in its lambda expressions. It can be quite annoying at times. I would suggest to find a way in which you can store what you want to check against in a variable, then just checking for

```
... && u.Password = myVariable);
```

Comment: That may work, however usually passwords are not just hashed but also salted, so comparison won't work for them. Better option is to obtain both hash and salt to client and do all calculations there.

Comment: My suggestion was doing the caluclations, then checking for equality. It doesn't work by precalculating a hash from the user's input, storing it in `myVariable`, then checking for eqality against the existing hash? It's been a while since I used hashes, that's why I upvoted Steven Robbins for being more complete, correct and elaborate ^^

Answer (score 0):

Why not to get user by name and then compare it's password with salt? Kind of

```
var CurrentUser = db.Users
    .FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == form["username"]); 
if (CurrentUser == null || !CurrentUser.Password.SequenceEqual(
                   MD5.Create().ComputeHash(
                           Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(form["password"])))) { ...user of password is incorrect.. }
```